Trying to understand the sensitivity of Bootstrap Switch Input Controls (R Shiny)
Considering the R Shiny code below,
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  switchInput("test1", "Destiny by Occupancy"),
  switchInput("test2", "Destiny by Origin"),
  switchInput("test3", "Destiny by Ownership")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

why is the second switch button larger than the other two? What is causing the size change?


No idea why that's happening but you can fix it by adding labelWidth = "80px". I'd say it's a bug so you might want to open an issue at https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues
